public function show(Product $product):View
I've recently started finiding my way through laravel and have a small question - Can somebody explain why the :view is written after the function is defined?
I did not understand the function and would want someone to explain to me.

Welcome to SO. It's not good that the downvoters didn't provide an explanation to you. But the reason of the downvotes is related to how you should ask a question. Just for you to get an idea, your question should reflect some of the research you've done, provide some reproducible code with some context, good punctuation and capitalize proper nouns also helps.

In Laravel, when you see :View after a function declaration such as
public function show() :View

This is an example of a return type declaration.
This feature is a part of PHP 7 and later, and it allow you to specify the type of the value that will be returned by the function.
In Laravel declaring a return type of :View indicates that the show() method will return a viwe instance. Here is how it look in a controller:
public function show($id) :View {
    $data['user'] = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('users.show, $data);
}

